# Angular ng-show not in sync with function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this frustrating problem with ng-show where it doesn't work in sync with function at all, like it is being completely ignored. I am trying to show button in ng-repeat element based on the function from controller which returns true/false.

**Function code in controller:**

```
   $scope.isRated = function(reservation){

            var reservationID = reservation.id;
            var guestEmail = $rootScope.USER.email;
            var json = JSON.stringify({
                "reservationID": reservationID,
                "guestEmail": guestEmail.toString(),
                "venueRating": $scope.foodRating,
                "restaurantRating":$scope.restaurantRating,
                "serviceRating":$scope.serviceRating
            });
            var url = "http://localhost:9900/api/reservation/isRated";

            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data : json,
                    success: function (response) {
                      //  alert(response + " " + reservationID);

                        return response;

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }

            );
```

**HTML div where it should occur:**

```
<p>{{USER.name}}</p>
<div class="row" ng-init="loadData()">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Passed reservations</label><br/>
        <div ng-repeat="x in restaurantHistory track by x.id">
            {{x.id}} {{x.restaurant.name}} <button ng-show="isRated(x)" ng-click="rateReservation(x)" class="btn btn-link">Rate</button>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <a href="#advanced">Advanced settings</a>
        <br/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Function works correctly, returns boolean as wanted but I just can't manage to find a way to connect it with the button element in html. I tried everything I could find on other questions but so far had no luck. There is none reported error, it just does not work as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isRated` is an asynchronous function. It makes an `http` request which doesn't complete right away, which is why a `success` callback exists. But the `isRated` function itself returns immediately, and since it has no return value it returns `undefined`. So `ng-show` sees `undefined` and never shows the element.

Each reservation can have an `isRated` property on it. Also, since `ng-show` will call `$scope.isRated` many times, you may want a `loadingInitiated` property as well, so you can cache the AJAX response and ensure you only make the AJAX request once:

```
$scope.isRated = function(reservation) {
    if (reservation.loadingInitiated) {
        return reservation.isRated;
    }

    reservation.loadingInitiated = true;

    $.ajax(
    {
        // ...
        success: function (response) {
          reservation.isRated = // ...
        }
    }
   );
}
```

Also note that you should probably use Angular's `$http` service to make AJAX calls instead of jQuery. This way, when the response returns, Angular is guaranteed to pick up the change and bind the new value to the view. Also, you could do your caching using that service too if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an async call. One way to get it working is updating a model that is watched by angular so the view is updated when it is changed.

1- Create a scope property with a default value

```
$scope.isRated = false;
```

2- Use the new property in your ng-show

```
<button ng-show="isRated">Button</button>
```

3- Update the the property `isRated` with your ajax call